# Wrapper, This does not look like a batch script

Tags: slurm

I want to pass arguments in a job. I write a wrapper in the file *job.sh* but when i use it i get a error:

```
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first
sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh
```

**main.sh**

```
DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
name='test__'$DATE
./job.sh $name
```

**job.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sbatch << EOT

#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=$1
#SBATCH --nodes=1                # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1     # number of cores

#module load R
Rscript script.R $1

EOT
```

**script.R**

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
print((args[[1]]))
```

(the three files are in the same directory)

Comment: Is it the second newline after EOT maybe? The blank line is the first line of the input if I´m not mistaken

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Indeed the problem came from the  newline after `sbatch <EOT`.
Thank for your help.